# When to create component dynamically in angular 2

Tags: angular2-template

I want to know that when we should create component dynamically i know with the help of ViewContainerRef and viewchild we can do that. But i wanted to know the use case when we should do that. because if we want to create a child component and insert it in parent we can anyways do that conventionally by inserting child component into parent component in template.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine throughout your app you have buttons that trigger different modals to open, In that case you can use Dynamic Component.